# ggvegan for the latest version of R

Tags: r, pca, rda

Is there an alternative to ggvegan for creating a pca plot in R version 4.0.0. I have used the rda function with the following script:

```
dput(mite.env)
pca<-rda(mite.env[,1:2])
summary(pca)
autoplot(pca, arrows = TRUE)
```

However, it appears that ggvegan is not available for the latest version of R. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
if (!require(devtools)) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

`devtools::install_github("githubadress")` should be always in your toolbelt as an R developer to fetch the newest up-to-date versions of an R package freshly from github.

I tried this with R 4.0.2 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Initially, I tried something similar (which are the lines of code following the # tags). I then tried your suggestion:              
```{r}
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
#devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
#library(ggvegan)
if (!require(devtools)) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
library(ggvegan)
```

Comment: This just updated my current packages and returned the same error :  Error in library(ggvegan) :  there is no package called ‘ggvegan’

Comment: I was able to get a plot up with this : biplot(pca,scaling = "symmetric") I'm not sure if it is as good though

Comment: No what is that?

Comment: Is R 4.0.2 the latest version of R

Comment: `conda` is a universal package manager. It can handle all languages. However, community must prepare the packages in a special way. Short but very good tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJC6ldI3hWk&t=6s

Comment: with conda, you can generate virtual environments. I generate for each R version I use a new environment. And then one can switch easily between different R versions.

Comment: are you in linux or windows or mac?

Comment: Awesome! I am on windows. By the way, I just updated to version 4.0.2 and was able to install ggvegan, which made a beautiful plot. Thanks for your help today.

Comment: welcome - please don't forget to accept and/or upvote - always in stackoverflow - people answering use their free time to answer ;)